# D3.js doesn´t draw graph after changing source from tsv to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a D3.js linegraph that i drew with using a TSV file. Now I have a JSON file with timestamp and value as keys. This is the code with the TSV file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
                .rangeRound([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0]);
        var line = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
        d3.tsv(" /data.tsv ", function(d) {
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            return d;
        }, function(error, data) {
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));
            g.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
                    .attr("x", 6)
                    .attr("dx", "1em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "begin   ")
                    .text("time")
                    .select(".domain")
                    .remove();
            g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Price ($)");
            g.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                    .attr("d", line);
        });
    }
    </script>
```

This is the code for the JSON file:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%y-%m-%d");

       @* x-Axis goes from 0 to width*@
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
                .rangeRound([0, width]);

        @* y-Axis goes from 0 to height*@
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0]);

        @* line generator, returns timestamp on x-axis and value on y-axis *@
        var line = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });



        d3.json(" /all.json ", function(d) {

            d.forEach(function(d){
                d.timestamp = d.timestamp;
                d.value = d.value;
                console.log(d.timestamp);
                console.log(d.value);
            });

            return d;
        }, function(error, data) {

            @* returns maximum and minimum of array d (data) *@
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));



            g.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
                    .attr("x", 6)
                    .attr("dx", "1em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "begin   ")
                    .text("time")
                    .select(".domain")
                    .remove();

            g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Price ($)");


            g.append("path")
                        @* https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_datum *@
                    .data(data)
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                    .attr("d", line);
        });

    }
```

The TSV file had the keys: "date" and "close".
My JSON object has the keys: "timestamp", "value" that i need and "valid", "channelid" that i do not need, so it is nearly identical.
An example JSON file looks like this:

```
Object { timestamp: "2017-10-15 19:45", ChannelID: 13, value: 65469, valid: false }
```

Why doesn´t D3 display the graph anymore? What do i need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `d3.tsv`, `d3.json` does **not** accept a row conversion function.

In your code...

```
d3.json("/all.json ", function(d) {
    d.forEach(function(d){
        d.timestamp = d.timestamp;
        d.value = d.value;
        console.log(d.timestamp);
        console.log(d.value);
    });
    return d;
}, function(error, data) {
```

... everything between `"/all.json "` and `function(error, data)` is the row conversion function.

**Solution**: move the row function to inside the callback...

```
d3.json("/all.json ", function(error, data) {
    //this is "inside the callback"
});
```

Or, alternatively, since it's not doing anything, just drop it.

Also, you have to parse your dates (which you are doing in the TSV version):

```
d3.json("/all.json ", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d){
        d.timestamp = parseTime(d.timestamp);
    });
    //the rest of the code
});
```

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but where exactly do i need to put it in? I am a d3.js noob

Comment: what does the plus actually do? i want to display the values explicitly, so if the value is 5, i want it to be 5 at the y-axis.

Comment: So i did what you told me and it shows the graph again but doesn´t draw anything. I guess this might be due the line itself. Thank you.

Comment: You have to parse the `timestamp` the same way you did with the TSV.

Comment: I used var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"); but it still doesn´t work..

Comment: This specifier is clearly incorrect, you don't have seconds or underscore in your strings. Besides that, those are **other** problems. Please, keep it one problem per question.